# Is there a way to disable constructor synthesizing on a class?

Tags: c++, gcc

Suppose I have a class that I want to make sure my compiler (GCC in this case) doesn't synthesize any constructors or assignment methods for. I've found one way to do this which is to just include a const int member in the class, but this doesn't rub me to well. Is there an attribute or something which signifies this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you define (or *only* declare) it yourself, then the compiler will not define it for you.

```
struct A
{
     A (); /*declaration is enough to prevent the compiler from 
             generating default constructor!*/
};
```

While the declaration is enough to prevent the compiler from generating default constructor, it is necessary to define it **if** your code requires the default constructor, otherwise you'll get linker error.

In C++11 (the new ISO Standard), you can disable constructors, copy-constructor, and copy-assignment as:

```
struct A
{
    A(const A&) = delete;            //disable copy-constructor
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete; //disable copy-assignment
};
```

---

### Now the interesting part

You can also selectively disable constructor(s) for *selected* types which makes `delete` more interesting. Consider this,

```
struct A
{
       A (int) {}
};
```

Object of this class can be created not only with `int` argument, but any type which implicitly converts to `int`.  For example,

```
A a1(10);  //ok
A a2('x'); //ok - char can convert to int implicitly

B b; 
A a3(b); //ok - assume b provides user-defined conversion to int
```

Now suppose, for whatever reason, I don't want the users of class `A` to create objects with `char` or `class B` , which fortunately or unfortunately can *implicitly* convert to `int`, then you can disable them as:

```
struct A
{
     A(int) {}
     A(char) = delete;      //disable
     A(const B&) = delete;  //disable
};
```

Now here you go:

```
A a1(10);  //ok
A a2('x'); //error

B b; 
A a3(b); //error - assume (even if) b provides user-defined conversion to int
```

Online Demo  : http://ideone.com/ZVyK7

The error messages are very clear:

> prog.cpp:9:5: error: deleted function 'A::A(char)'
> prog.cpp:10:5: error: deleted function 'A::A(const B&)'

Comment: Don't want to spam comments but this answer is just too awesome!!

Comment: @ithenoob: Thanks. You can see this also: [What's the exact semantics of a deleted function in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265920/whats-the-exact-semantics-of-a-deleted-function-in-c11)

Answer (score 15):

The classical way is to declare them, but never implement. Most people would expect that declaration to be private or protected.

In C++0x, you can explicitly delete them. Which does pretty much the same thing, but is way nicer to read.

Comment: Note also that boost has a `boost::noncopyable` class that can be used as a private base in a class that wants to delete the copy constructor (and `operator=`)