# Not copyable object and exception in copy constructor and operator=

Tags: c++, exception

I'd like to make object of class not copyable so I put copy constructor and operator= in private section. However one class is friend of this class so it has access to private methods. Is it good idea to put throw exception in copy constructor and operator= to be sure that object will not be copied?

Comment: Note that you should take the given advice always, not only if you have friends, because the class itself shouldn't be able to make copies of its kind either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach to make it not copyable is just to declare the copy constructor, but don't implement it at all. That will force a linker error at compile time if anyone tries to use it.

```
class foo
{
private:
    foo(const foo&); // not defined
    foo& operator=(const foo&); // not defined
};
```

Answer (score 3):

@Mysticial have answered this question which is usually done in C++03. But in C++11, you can do this, more nicely:

```
class foo
{
private:
    foo(const foo&) = delete; 
    foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete; 
};
```

The `=delete` conveys the message that `foo` doesn't support copy-semantic, as it has been disabled by explicitly marking it with `delete`. I've explained this in detail here:

- [Is there a way to disable constructor synthesizing on a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151383/is-there-a-way-to-disable-constructor-synthesizing-on-a-class)

Comment: @BrendanLong: I edited the post with a link. Please go through that.