# Should I delete the move constructor and the move assignment of a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I'm implementing a simple smart pointer, which basically keeps track of the number of references to a pointer that it handles.

I know I *could* implement move semantics, but I don't think it makes sense as copying a smart pointer is very cheap. Especially considering that it introduces opportunities to produce nasty bugs.

Here's my C++11 code (I omitted some inessential code). General comments are welcome as well.

```
#ifndef SMART_PTR_H_
#define SMART_PTR_H_

#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
class SmartPtr {
private:
    struct Ptr {
        T* p_;
        uint64_t count_;
        Ptr(T* p) : p_{p}, count_{1} {}
        ~Ptr() { delete p_; }
    };
public:
    SmartPtr(T* p) : ptr_{new Ptr{p}} {}
    ~SmartPtr();

    SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& rhs);
    SmartPtr(SmartPtr<T>&& rhs) =delete;

    SmartPtr<T>& operator=(const SmartPtr<T>& rhs);
    SmartPtr<T>& operator=(SmartPtr<T>&& rhs) =delete;

    T& operator*() { return *ptr_->p_; }
    T* operator->() { return ptr_->p_; }

    uint64_t Count() const { return ptr_->count_; }

    const T* Raw() const { return ptr_->p_; }
private:
    Ptr* ptr_;
};

template<typename T>
SmartPtr<T>::~SmartPtr() {
    if (!--ptr_->count_) {
        delete ptr_;
    }
    ptr_ = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& rhs) : ptr_{rhs.ptr_} {
    ++ptr_->count_;
}

template<typename T>
SmartPtr<T>& SmartPtr<T>::operator=(const SmartPtr<T>& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        if (!--ptr_->count_) {
            delete ptr_;
        }
        ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;
        ++ptr_->count_;
    }
    return *this;
}

#endif // SMART_PTR_H_
```

Comment: No. If you want everything to be a copy, then don't declare the move members; don't define them as deleted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489837/why-do-deleted-move-semantics-cause-problems-with-stdvector

Comment: You are exactly right about the `operator*`! Yikes! Corrected.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has custom move operations because the underlying reference counting mechanism is concurrency-safe. The custom move operations can therefore avoid the atomic increment.

Comment: Well, if you want to know some good way, then lock `std::shared_ptr` code.

Comment: "Copying a smart pointer is cheap", but moving one must be cheaper - no need for any atomics or locking, given we're not touching the count?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Guideline**

*Never* delete the special move members.

In typical code (such as in your question), there are two motivations to delete the move members.  One of those motivations produces incorrect code (as in your example), and for the other motivation the deletion of the move members is redundant (does no harm nor good).

1. If you have a copyable class and you don't want move members, simply don't declare them (which includes not deleting them).  Deleted members are still declared.  Deleted members participate in overload resolution.  Members not present don't.  When you create a class with a valid copy constructor and a deleted move member, you can't return it by value from a function because overload resolution will bind to the deleted move member.
2. Sometimes people want to say:  this class is neither movable nor copyable.  It is correct to delete both the copy and the move members.  However just deleting the copy members is sufficient (as long as the move members are not declared).  Declared (even deleted) copy members *inhibit* the compiler from declaring move members.  So in this case the deleted move members are simply redundant.

If you declare deleted move members, even if you happen to pick the case where it is redundant and not incorrect, every time someone reads your code, they need to re-discover if your case is redundant or incorrect.  Make it easier on readers of your code and never delete the move members.

**The incorrect case:**

```
struct CopyableButNotMovble
{
    // ...
    CopyableButNotMovble(const CopyableButNotMovble&);
    CopyableButNotMovble& operator=(const CopyableButNotMovble&);
    CopyableButNotMovble(CopyableButNotMovble&&) = delete;
    CopyableButNotMovble& operator=(CopyableButNotMovble&&) = delete;
    // ...
};
```

Here is example code you probably expected to work with `CopyableButNotMovble` but will fail at compile time:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct CopyableButNotMovble
{
    // ...
    CopyableButNotMovble(const CopyableButNotMovble&);
    CopyableButNotMovble& operator=(const CopyableButNotMovble&);
    CopyableButNotMovble(CopyableButNotMovble&&) = delete;
    CopyableButNotMovble& operator=(CopyableButNotMovble&&) = delete;

    CopyableButNotMovble(int);
    // ...
    friend bool operator<(CopyableButNotMovble const& x, CopyableButNotMovble const& y); 
};

int
main()
{
    std::vector<CopyableButNotMovble> v{3, 2, 1};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}

In file included from test.cpp:1:
algorithm:3932:17: error: no
      matching function for call to 'swap'
                swap(*__first, *__last);
                ^~~~
algorithm:4117:5: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__sort<std::__1::__less<CopyableButNotMovble,
      CopyableButNotMovble> &, CopyableButNotMovble *>' requested here
    __sort<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __comp);
    ^
algorithm:4126:12: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::sort<CopyableButNotMovble *,
      std::__1::__less<CopyableButNotMovble, CopyableButNotMovble> >' requested here
    _VSTD::sort(__first, __last, __less<typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>());
           ^
...
```

(many nasty error messages from deep inside your std::lib)

The correct way to do this is:

```
struct CopyableButNotMovble
{
    // ...
    CopyableButNotMovble(const CopyableButNotMovble&);
    CopyableButNotMovble& operator=(const CopyableButNotMovble&);
    // ...
};
```

**The redundant case:**

```
struct NeitherCopyableNorMovble
{
    // ...
    NeitherCopyableNorMovble(const NeitherCopyableNorMovble&) = delete;
    NeitherCopyableNorMovble& operator=(const NeitherCopyableNorMovble&) = delete;
    NeitherCopyableNorMovble(NeitherCopyableNorMovble&&) = delete;
    NeitherCopyableNorMovble& operator=(NeitherCopyableNorMovble&&) = delete;
    // ...
};
```

The more readable way to do this is:

```
struct NeitherCopyableNorMovble
{
    // ...
    NeitherCopyableNorMovble(const NeitherCopyableNorMovble&) = delete;
    NeitherCopyableNorMovble& operator=(const NeitherCopyableNorMovble&) = delete;
    // ...
};
```

It helps if you make a practice of always grouping all 6 of your special members near the top of your class declaration, in the same order, skipping those you don't want to declare.  This practice makes it easier for readers of your code to quickly determine that you have intentionally not declared any particular special member.

For example, here is the pattern I follow:

```
class X
{
    // data members:

public:
    // special members
    ~X();
    X();
    X(const X&);
    X& operator=(const X&);
    X(X&&);
    X& operator=(X&&);

    // Constructors
    // ...
};
```

[Here is a more in-depth explanation of this declaration style.](http://howardhinnant.github.io/classdecl.html)

Comment: I don't see the "produces incorrect code (as in your example)". What is incorrect in the code? Do I overlook that specific explanation here? Are you referring to "=delete does not mean "don't use me, instead use next best one". It rather means, "don't use me when you need me — instead be alone in the wild."" from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19266022/472245 or something else?

Comment: @towi:  I've added an example to clarify.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @HowardHinnant "When you create a class with a valid copy constructor and a deleted move member, you can't return it by value from a function because overload resolution will bind to the deleted move member." I had no idea about this. Thanks!

Comment: With C++17 guaranteed copy elision on return, the underlying mechanics have changed so 1 no longer applies. In case of 2. I now recommend to just delete the move assignment operator, because that is the minimal thing to do to get rid of copying and moving, while retaining defaulted default constructor.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I agree with your answer, although it requires some knowledge about the exact rules when the compiler defines default operations (which should be expected from a good C++ programmer anyway). One question: it seems that your answer contradicts to [this C++ FAQ entry](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-default-operation-define-or-delete-them-all) - as a committee member, do you see the necessity of updating this?

Comment: That wouldn't be the first core guideline I disagreed with. :-)  One can never get 100% agreement on anything within any sizeable group of people.  So when you see me say something, I'm just representing myself and not the committee.  And I try to speak only about areas I'm knowledgable and passionate about.  If enough people agree with me about something like this, it is up to them to let the authors of the Core Guidelines know.  And if not, we can all agree to respectfully disagree.