# MSVC cannot return an object that can be copied but cannot be moved

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, language-lawyer, copy-elision

While fiddling around with copy elision I came across this strange behavior:

```
class Obj {
 public:
  Obj() = default;

  Obj(Obj&&) = delete;
  Obj(const Obj&) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
};

Obj f1() {
  Obj o;
  return o; // error C2280: move constructor is deleted
}

Obj f2() {
  Obj o;
  return Obj(o); // this however works fine
}

int main() {
  Obj p = f1();
  Obj q = f2();

  return 0;
}
```

GCC and Clang accept this code and are able to use copy elision in both cases.

In `f1()` MSVC complains that it cannot return `o` because the move constructor of `Obj` is deleted. However, I would expect it to be able to fall back on the copy constructor. **Is this a bug in MSVC or is this desired behavior (that I don't understand) and GCC / Clang are too permissive?**

If I provide a move constructor, MSVC is able to elide the move when compiling as *Release*.

Interestingly MSVC is able to compile `f2()`. As far as I understand this is due to the mandatory copy elision when the result of a constructor call is returned. However it feels counter-intuitive that I am only able to return `o` by-value if I manually copy it.

I know that this situation might not be relevant for practical use since copyable objects usually are also moveable, but I am interested in the underlying mechanics.

Here is the online example for testing: https://godbolt.org/z/sznds7

Comment: In f1 copy elision is optional in f2 not. Msvc is right but gcc and clang too. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @Bernd I understand that part. But the core of the question remains: Why does MSVC not just use the copy constructor (without optimizing anything)?

Comment: My understanding is that if the move constructor is selected by overload resolution and it is deleted, compiling should fail whether or not it would be elided.

Comment: Declaring a function deleted is not the same as omitting it entirely. A deleted function still participates in overload resolution, and if actually chosen, the program is ill-formed. Just drop the move constructor; the compiler will not implicitly declare it when a user-defined copy constructor exists.

Comment: While `delete`d functions do participate in overload resolution, there appears to be an [exception](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#funcs.general-9) for special member functions, where they are explicitly ignored. Looks like a MSVC bug to me.

Comment: @cigien - does that apply?  this move constructor isn't a _defaulted_ move (`= default`) ...

Comment: It should also be noted that a type with a copy constructor but *no* move constructor is a kind of broken type. There's (almost) no reason to create such a type, as the move constructor could just do what the copy constructor does.

Comment: That's not exactly right. The quote is "A defaulted move special member function ([class.copy.ctor], [class.copy.assign]) that is defined as deleted is excluded from the set of candidate functions in all contexts." So this covers `=delete` I think.

Comment: @cigien - but in the example given in that section the move constructor being discussed, for `struct B`, is `= default`, but it is "defined" deleted because `struct B` contains a member which is a struct which has a deleted (`= delete`) move constructor ...

Comment: Hmm, ok, I may be misunderstanding what "defined as deleted" means in that quote.

Comment: @cigien When a special member function is declared as defaulted, the compiler provides an implicit definition following a set of rules. Sometimes, these rules say that the function should be deleted (e.g. a move constructor for a class that has a non-movable member); then the function is "defined as deleted". In this case, the overload resolution behaves as if the function weren't declared at all.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, that makes a lot more sense now. I was clearly misreading that text. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The lack of error on `f1()` is a bug in both clang and gcc.  [It is fixed in clang's tip-of-trunk.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i3wXXsVmoGrJN7qM)

`f1()` is not eligible for mandatory copy elision.

Deleted functions participate in overload resolution.  If they are chosen as the best overload, the program is ill-formed.  In `f1()`, the deleted move constructor is chosen by overload resolution.

In `f2()`, [as of C++17, copy/move elision is guaranteed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html), and thus overload resolution on the move/copy constructors is not done.  In C++11/14, `f2()` is also an error (same error as `f1()`) because copy/move elision is *not* guaranteed.

Also see this guideline: [*Never* delete the special move members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820178/576911), which admittedly was written prior to C++17.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on part of this, it sounds like you're saying that GCC/Clang resolved to the deleted move constructor. Is that A) the bug in the compiler, B) defined behavior in the spec, or C) undefined behavior (making it not a bug)? It sounds like you're saying C, so `f1` would always have undefined behavior with objects that have a deleted move constructor. If that's the case, was the bug that GCC/Clang defined a move constructor without a copy constructor? Is it a bug if it's UB?

Comment: The first sentence in the answer is the entire answer.  Everything else is supporting information for the first sentence.

Comment: @jrh Ill formed programs are not UB.  Ill formed programs require a diagnostic (an error).  Ill formed programs, no diagnostic required, can compile and generate UB, but this isn't a ill-formed NDR case; last I counted, you could count ill-formed NDR cases on one hand.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk-AdamNevraumont.  You understood jrh's question where I did not.  Good answer.  After the decades roll by in this line of work, I've fallen into the trap of mistaking standards-speak for plain english.

Answer (score 12):

**oh, I feel ashamed, I just realized that the other answer is by Howard Hinnant, the one person whose writings made me understand what I am painfully trying to explain here, it's a bit ridiculous...**

Since copy and move constructors are both declared, they both exist.
Especially here, you took care to define yourself the copy constructor; without that it would have been defined deleted (see p28 of [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014)).

The *deleted* aspect is just detail about the definition, but they are both actually declared then **eligible to overload resolution**.
In `f1()` if the copy elision occurs, then there is no need to choose between copy and move constructor; none of these is used.
On the other hand, if the copy elision does not occur, then the best overload has to be chosen to construct the result; here this is the move constructor because it exists (it is declared, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters)), and finally the definition is discovered as deleted, but it is too late, the choice is already made.

In `f2()`, an explicit copy is explicitly requested, then the copy constructor is the best choice.

Which is quite confusing, is that when we read `=delete` we think « this cannot be chosen in overload resolution » but this is wrong; `=delete` is only considered **after** overload resolution when it is too late to find a better match.

Comment: Not so much ridiculous as it is funny, looks like you got some tuff competition ;) I do appreciate your effort so it's an upvote for me.

Comment: As anastaciu says, it's more amusing than anything else. It's *definitely* nothing to be ashamed of. We all learn from each other; that's just how it goes :)

Comment: I actually like this answer better since it explains the overload resolution of the deleted method in far more detail