# What is the minimal class to extend for a no copy / no move type?

Tags: c++, rule-of-three, rule-of-five

Let's say I want to create some classes to manage resources that shouldn't be copied nor moved, which would be the minimal class to extend and avoid mistakes?

The idea is that by extending the class, I end on the safe side of the [0/3/5 rules](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rule+of+0+3+5&atb=v177-1&ia=web).

I have this in mind, which apparently works.

```cpp
class NOCOPYNOMOVE {
    NOCOPYNOMOVE(NOCOPYNOMOVE &v) = delete;
    NOCOPYNOMOVE(NOCOPYNOMOVE &&v) = delete;
    NOCOPYNOMOVE& operator=(NOCOPYNOMOVE &r) = delete;
    NOCOPYNOMOVE& operator=(NOCOPYNOMOVE &&r) = delete;
};

class Foo: private NOCOPYNOMOVE {
public:
    Foo() {}
    ~Foo() {}
};
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I think you'r pretty close, not sure you need to delete operator=(&&). I never do it, but maybe it is a learning point for me. I also would make the default constructor protected. That way you can't accidentally make instances.

Comment: @PKramer I think it is indeed not needed as it won't be automatically generated, but this is more explicit.

Comment: When asking about `minimal` - you could omit the parameter names. So `(NOCOPYNOMOVE &)` instead of `(NOCOPYNOMOVE &v)`.

Comment: @asmmo I have posted what appears to be a solution, but I'm not sure whether it is correct, since C++ can be very tricky (ideally, everything would be "delete" by default).

Comment: *... it is indeed not needed...* and *...the minimal class...* seem to be in conflict.

Comment: It's [been done](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html).

Answer (score 2):

- Don't need to delete move constructor, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820178/2945027
- Avoid `ALL_CAPS` name, as it is conventionally by every convention used for macros
- There's no reason to omit `const` in copy constructor/assignment, so the usual form should be preferred
- If classes would inherit from some `NOCOPYNOMOVE` in some namespace, it may trigger unintended ADL. `boost::noncopyable` solves it by putting the definition in `noncopyable_` namespace, see the [implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/boost/core/noncopyable.hpp)
- I'd prefer just not having some base, instead spelling out these two or three lines in the target class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    ~Foo() {}

    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I was using `ALL_CAPS` because I was thinking on writing something like a macro.  Would be interesting to add the two lines as a macro too, but I don't know whether it is possible to get the class name inside the macro. Adding the last 2 lines by itself does not make the intention clear.