# Consequences of and alternatives to use std::forward on non-forwarding-reference type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++14

I am writing a factory. Both "interface" and the "implementation" are defined by template classes.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<class I, class ...Args>
struct IFactory
{
  virtual std::unique_ptr<I> Create(Args... args) = 0;
};

template<class I, class C, class ...Args>
struct Factory : IFactory<I, Args...>
{
  std::unique_ptr<I> Create(Args... args) override
  {
    return std::make_unique<C>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // args are no forwarding references
  }
};
```

The code violates the sonar source rule [RSPEC-5417](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-5417), which states:

> std::forward has a *single use-case*: to cast a templated function parameter of type forwarding reference (`T&&`) to the value category (lvalue or rvalue) the caller used to pass it.
> [...]
> An error [...] has *less dire consequences* [than using `std::move` on a forwarding reference], and might even work as intended if the right template argument is used, but the code would be *clumsy* and *not clearly express the intent*.
> [*Emphasis* by me]

I wonder,

- what are the *less dire consequences* if wrong template arguments used?
- what are the wrong template arguments?
- how to ensure the right template parameters are used?
- how to write the code less *clumsy* and *express intent* more clearly?

I considered to use `static_cast<Args&&>()` directly, but that would make the code less readable in my opinion and i think it would only re-implement `std::forward`.

Example usage of `Factory<...>` shows that `Factory::Create()` generates one additional move construction (for the ctor argument `T1 a`, in the example below):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void P(std::string msg){std::cout << msg << std::endl;} // Debug print

// Some types used as ctor arguments types of the class for which we want to create objects.
struct T1{T1()=default; T1(const T1&){P("T1&");} T1(T1&&){P("T1&&");}}; // Move- and copyable
struct T2{T2()=default; T2(const T2&){P("T2&");} T2(T2&&)=delete;    }; // Copyable
struct T3{T3()=default; T3(const T3&)=delete;    T3(T3&&){P("T3&&");}}; // Moveable
struct T4{T4()=default; T4(const T4&)=delete;    T4(T4&&)=delete;    }; // None of move/copy

// Interface of the class
struct IType
{ /*Some pure virtual functions.*/
};

struct Type : IType
{
  T1  t1;
  T2  t2;
  T3  t3;
  T4& t4;
  Type(T1 a, const T2& b, T3&& c, T4& d)
  :t1(a), t2(b), t3(std::move(c)), t4(d) {}
};

void F(const IFactory<IType, T1, const T2&, T3&&, T4&>& factory)
{
  T1 t1;
  T2 t2;
  T3 t3a, t3b;
  T4 t4;
  std::cout << "Ctor:\n";
  Type obj1(t1, t2, std::move(t3a), t4);
  std::cout << "Factory:\n";
  auto ptri1 = factory.Create(t1, t2, std::move(t3b), t4);
}

int main()
{
  Factory<IType, Type, T1, const T2&, T3&&, T4&> factory1;
  F(factory1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Ctor:
T1&
T1&
T2&
T3&&
Factory:
T1&
T1&&         <- additional move for the not optimal ctor argument
T1&
T2&
T3&&
```

[Example on gobolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TEABWAHZydwAZAiZsADk/ACNsUikLcgAHdCViFyYvX38g0Iys5yFI6Li2ROSeVIdsJxyRIhZSIjy/AJD7bEdSpmbWonLYhKSU%2Bxa2joLupSnhqNGq8dqASnt0H1JUTi5LAGYo1F8cAGozA48ONjIAT0vcMy0AQWeXomw2NKNPy48TiwlEozgBJchnQHAs4AOjhL1IwCUj3e81IPicYIAYiwnPd3mZgjZXmdSWcAG4ENo%2BCRneaYEAgHxMAgARx82AA%2BmkiKR/qDHmcPKRsCxPhAEUi4TCzq0kWtIUJ5hcDgARM5aS7Et7BVVagmvT7fX7Yf5QkHgyFGaEeCHm2HwxHIg5PV5ojFEM44vGkO5nEDY3EkX38iGSpTSlGvQna0n0xnMtkc7m8/mC4Wi8Xh6Wyp0KjBMZXoclJUgEHDvUkxysXLQAThFRG2TDpRAZIDYLAA1lzE%2BzTVcPI8IPGQIJSAB3VqYf7h4dypRraVrfUki66gkbg7agkWI5ME4%2Bc7/NFRYBRt5746nbAqjwuNGitgX97k9Dls6qEdtxmnkxnNglGAFciVHDAfE9f5/gAoC72g0d3HofUN2jN1eQ9M4ABUeBjbCIBXNUcBoFgfHoIgtSwngIALZVsMsAA2ECrC/SwLDoix6NYgibF1SiIHYziOKYliLDYnCOIYrjkPVQk9W3VF0MxTCLFwix8MuVUiJIsiKOU6ilU9ZSGOEiBWKMiTRO42SsLU8zBMYjScEYP5tzJKst21d0lIOXCDnUwjsGI0jyNczC/JowyfKExzemwFyrDcrC/LCyToqJES2Ki%2BypPkjcPIU9ElOkXDpH8zTAu0kKEsw0qIqw4rooC5yBwStyav4hr7II8rmooslZNXN40MKz1QUwu40lNaMiU3OSd2GjDxsm/0wSWqadVjSjSSIHD5LXZTtpUvaXlJMLtp847Ts6s4iGKy6sIm7B%2BJ4WU7QMmyGLOeIIRSiz6MhH7rswFc1xAHaIBYDYbrU%2BIoaIPzR1uEtqLWOHSuB9ceL1aa5oNF43w/LF9MLUbvWDB4rjGx6fp4N6SY%2BjifqyhjAckl1PuIn07hBjaa2wm7ds2g6iCOoWDhug4WAheH4kGq6bruzawK2SCrmg1iPGDEAzECDwmFYuWHuW9B4l0Kidul1JW3bJGnvhyHpekKy12ViC4KuC5RLJ%2B5td1/XRMNkiSDOHkyxejSzk58mYQzMU7dp6GIUR4s7YOWHHednVsaGl4ok9TsoggPPc2AVA7SQVoACpK5L8keerNdvZDSm1p%2B6nKLp2iVMZpLUvo1mJJdSOg3uQWayJqPR8z0lG2bDVBtkrgNnobhAn4AIuB0ch0G4IdrFsOkth2W9Dj4cgiG0JeNi7IItEMbhpH4NgQHo6QYS0ej6x4A5gi0QJAgABw/37hvLeO8uD8CUCAO%2BF9N5L3IHAWAKAVZpAgpQagGBvgMFWGEQgWtaaCGEGICQnAZByGEMoNQmg4HnxFHsM%2BE5SAsDSJfZeq916X23twAA8hBVBnp0A0DOOoAB9EAC0r8zil1QGcCA6EmBdgVBALwWDGCkE9gcHgax%2BCwJ0KjcgSBRQ4GSPhe%2BXBH7kGfgcQIMI6wHDrFoURFg6zSGkDweiFhZCgP4OAyB0Dz6sOvi/N%2B9E6x1mCAcABDiDj2OkBYQIZiDgcJob4gJcCNiIOQGgdAqikjoP0rk5ISJWBpCUEgdARABAME%2BKQKBEB4icPiFEVodxuBn0wRwYQ3CmD0FaTQnAnYTCSH6VSBozgSxQJodgdQDQIJ7C3nnXonD6AEHiEw30XgcCcN5AQZ%2BvB4E0CMEiAAagQbAE5uGTQ3mfQhohxCSDIbcyhGhOH6FpkYEwaBbC2EMKsqBkANjoB5DkSZYj6QaXMPvawMhIGxUaK4CA7gZgBFphEJYlRqgGGKNkIQyKsWZBxUwEYGKcH1HhQMBYeLaZkv6IMNoxKxg1EmEMKlzL6XosZVIDYSgj67AMLybA9D4Ery4Gvcg3iuFcBEeIyR0jZHyMUbIveNhrAQnwMQMgGiE4qLSNg9Rp9tFpL0UE6xMIDhaC0BxHg9Z6KfxCNIBJIqLHP2tXfCVqSoEwMCWYiwySwHcB0d6kstScggGkEAA%3D)

Comment: You shouldn’t really ever delete a move constructor—it causes dumb things to happen during overload resolution (necessitating a special rule for *implicitly-declared* deleted move constructors).  Just declaring a copy constructor—even as defaulted—is enough to make a class copyable but “not movable”.

Comment: @DavisHerring, can you explain what dumb things happen if you take T(T&&) out of overload resolution? To me it looks like a good thing, because it can turn a performance bug into a compile-time error.

Comment: The whole problem is that it isn’t removed from consideration for overload resolution.  `std::move` *grants permission* for the recipient to consume the object, and it’s [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37092864/8586227) to say “you mustn’t have such permission”.  The converse, “permission to copy” as a performance gatekeeper, just doesn’t exist (partly because the `int`s would always need it in the current system).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @DavisHerring. I learned, that my wording in my post above was wrong. `T(T&&) = delete` *adds* the move-ctor to the overloads (as deleted), not removes it.
Anyhow, i leave my test-code for my original question as it is, because i want it to create reasonable results even for unusual user-classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a template argument is **deduced** other than from a forwarding reference, it is never deduced as a reference: then `std::forward<T>` is just the overload set

```
T&& forward(T&);
T&& forward(T&&);
```

which behaves exactly like `std::move`.  If the function parameter was declared as `T&`, this is **misleading**: the argument will be moved from, so the function should probably accept an rvalue (or forwarding) reference instead.

If the function parameter is just `T`, `std::forward` is **harmless** since the parameters are your own objects, but you might as well just use `std::move`.

Your case, however, is a bit different: this interface requires **explicit** template arguments, which can be references at the discretion of the client.  If it’s not a reference, it again behaves like `std::move`.  If it is, then `std::forward` reproduces the same kind of reference, which seems to be the **correct** behavior.

For completeness, consider the case of explicitly specifying the template argument for a function that accepts `T&`: regardless of the reference status of the template argument, the function will accept an **lvalue** reference, and will move from it(!) if the template argument is itself not a reference or an rvalue reference.  The same two cases will result in a move when `forward`ing a non-forwarding `T&&` parameter, but then the (function) argument must be an **rvalue**.

In conclusion, using `std::forward<T>` when the parameter is **`T&`** is wrong whether or not `T` is deduced, but is correct for `T` or `T&&` regardless.  The quoted guideline is too **strict** in that case: the deduced-`T` case should just be `std::move`, but your usage is useful and correct.