# Identification of automatically generated move assignment operator

Tags: c++, automatic-properties, move-assignment-operator

What is the automatically generated move assignment operator for a class `Number` that contains only one attribute of type `std::shared_ptr<Vertex>`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Vertex{
    Vertex(Vertex&&)=delete;
    Vertex(Vertex const&)=delete;
    void operator=(Vertex&&)=delete;
    void operator=(Vertex const&)=delete;
private:
    const size_t index;
public:
    Vertex()/*.index initialization.*/{}
};

class Number{
private:
    mutable std::shared_ptr<Vertex> vtx=NULL;
public:
    Number(){}
    const Number& operator=(const Number& rhs ){
        if(vtx==NULL){ vtx=std::shared_ptr<Vertex>( new Vertex() ); }
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
    //const Number& operator=(Number&& rhs) = delete; // <-- critical line
    const Number& operator+=(const Number& rhs);
};

Number operator+(const Number& a, const Number& b){
    Number x;
    // ...
    return x;
}

const Number& Number::operator+=(const Number& rhs){
    return (*this + rhs);
}


int main() {
    Number u,v,w;
    w = u;
    w += v;
    return 0;
}
```

We have been using this code and it yielded the intended behaviour when the critical line is commented out. We had been unaware that the compiler is generating this operator automatically. Now, because we cannot delete it since it is actually being critical for the program to function, we would like to know precisely its code. Can someone state it?

We have tried a couple of implementations ourselves that yield an unintended behaviour. Since the automatically generated one does precisely what we need, we would really like to identify it.

Comment: It's not being generated because `operator=(const Number& rhs )` exists. Deleting it explicitly is harmful and doesn't do anything useful, it will just give you errors when the rhs is a mutable rvalue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you. Okay so I run into the special case of rhs being a mutable rvalue and that is relevant for the issue. This is good to know! Now what I then don't undestand is how deletion of something that is _not_ generated can be harmful. Since it is not generated, deletion should mean no alteration to the class definition from my present incorrect understanding. What am I missing?

Comment: Deleted functions still participate in overload resolution (and cause a compilation error when selected by it). If you do this: `Number foo(); Number n; n = foo();`, if you don't delete the move assignment, the copy assignment will silently be used in its place, which is good. But if you do delete it, the deleted version is a better match, and you get a build error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Ah!!, this makes so much sense. So the logical argument for the design is that with deleting a function/operator one not foremost intends to prevent its generation, but to flag that it is not to be intended to used or even resolved. Wow, and I cannot even explicitize it by defining the operator with code myself, because I do not have the object Number const& rhs at hand but only a Number&&.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Your explanation could be useful to many others, but in the present question that is downvoted it probably won't be suggested or found. Certainly this was due to my conceptual misunderstanding of what the issue is. Do you have improvement suggestions for title/ presentation?

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that a deleted constructor (and others) is considered to be user-defined. It pretty much exists (if you look for it) and doesn't exist (if you try to use it) at the same time.

Comment: @GRamon You asked a pretty specific thing (what the default assignment operator does), and it's still unanswered. It now seems that you don't want that answered, but rather you wanted to understand some specific problem in your code, and some comments help you understand it. But it's not clear (to me) what your real question was, and how it was answered. In this situation, this question is not very useful. Maybe it could be useful if someone answered it, but it would only help someone else, and not you.

Comment: *"could be useful to many others"* I guess I could ask a new dummy question ("why shouldn't delete move operations when...") and self-answer it, but writing a proper full answer takes time, and I don't think I want to bother. I'd just leave this question as is.

Comment: [Guideline: Never delete the special move members.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820178/580083)